# Constructing components from PLSR loadings in R

Tags: r, pls

I want to compute the components for a set of variables using the loadings (weights) from a PLSR using the `plsr` function.

I thought that the components were computed by summing the values of each variable multiplied by the estimated loading (weight).

However, using the output from `plsr` and doing that doesn't give me the expected values:

**Example:**

```
library("pls")
data(oliveoil)
sens.pcr <- plsr(sensory ~ chemical, ncomp = 4, scale = F, data = oliveoil)
```

Extract loadings/weights:

```
df <- cbind(sens.pcr$loadings[,1],sens.pcr$loadings[,2],sens.pcr$loadings[,3],sens.pcr$loadings[,4])
```

One test observation:

```
firstrow <- oliveoil$chemical[1,]
```

Extract the components (scores):

```
scores <- sens.pcr$scores
```

Do the linear combination:

```
sum(firstrow*df[,1])
[1] -12.81924
```

Which is not equal to the first score `scores[1,1]` = `0.5100166`

What is it that I am missing?

Using the `sense.pcr$loadings.weigths` didn't make any big difference either.